# When using simple_form in Rails, how can I use it just to show data for some of the fields rather than have inputs?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, simple-form

I'm creating my forms using simple_form and it's all good, apart from when I want to just display some text rather than show an input box of some type.  So I need to show a label and also the display text to go with it, e.g.  Name :  Chris,   where "Name" is the label and "Chris" is the display text.

So Imagine I have a simple_form :

```
=simple_form_for @property do |f|
  =f.display_field "Contact Name",  "Chris"
  =f.input :customer_reference
  =f.input :premises_description
  =f.input :po_number, :label=>"Purchase Order Number"
```

The "f.display_field" is a made up method, but it is how I imagine the method would look that I need.  All it would do Is show a label and some text next to it.  What is the easiest way to achieve this?

Cheers
Chris

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I use a custom input for this purpose:

```
class FakeInput < SimpleForm::Inputs::Base
  # This method usually returns input's html like <input ... />
  # but in this case it returns just a value of the attribute.
  def input
    @builder.object.send(attribute_name)
  end
end
```

If you place it somewhere like in app/inputs/fake_input.rb
you will be able to use it in your simple forms:

```
= simple_form_for @property do |f|
  = f.input :contact_name, :as => :fake
```

The input's type is derived from the input's class name (without "Input", underscored).
So for FakeInput it is :fake.

Comment: Don't forget to restart your Rails server so that the new directory "app/inputs" is picked up.

Comment: Is it possible wrap the text in a span and pass some attribute to this span?

Comment: You can use regular helper methods in `def input` through `template`. For example, `template.content_tag('span', @builder.object.send(attribute_name))`.

Answer (score 1):

To display some regular text instead of an input simply pass a block (and extra label in case it is no model attribute):

```
= simple_form_for @property do |f|
  = f.input :contact_name, label: "Contact Name" do 
    Chris
  = f.input :customer_reference
  = f.input :premises_description
  = f.input :po_number, :label => "Purchase Order Number"
```

This will simply output `Chris` at the same place where the input would be otherwise.

Answer (score -2):

If I understand you correctly:

```
=simple_form_for @property do |f|
  Contact Name:
  =@property.contact_name
  =f.input :customer_reference
  =f.input :premises_description
  =f.input :po_number, :label=>"Purchase Order Number"
```

Comment: This won't format the field with divs (and the rest) like simple_form does with normal fields.